# mySQL max value correspond

Tags: mysql

I searched high and low and tried many methods, and still not the result i m looking for so here is the problem

here is my fields

```
cntrycd | date        | type | desc | value

tn      | 2013-08-16  | pr   | for  | 112 <--
tn      | 2013-08-15  | pr   | for  | 114 
tn      | 2013-08-14  | pr   | for  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | pr   | agn  | 118 <-- 
tn      | 2013-08-15  | pr   | agn  | 117 
tn      | 2013-08-14  | pr   | agn  | 112 
tn      | 2013-08-15  | pr   | mid  | 114 
tn      | 2013-08-14  | pr   | mid  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | pr   | mid  | 118 <-- 
tn      | 2013-08-15  | pr   | agn  | 117 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | ot   | for  | 112 <--
tn      | 2013-08-15  | ot   | for  | 114 
tn      | 2013-08-14  | ot   | for  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | ot   | agn  | 118 <--
tn      | 2013-08-15  | ot   | agn  | 117 
tn      | 2013-08-14  | ot   | agn  | 112 
tn      | 2013-08-15  | ot   | mid  | 114 
tn      | 2013-08-14  | ot   | mid  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | ot   | mid  | 118 <--
```

what i want is to get the max date and the corresponding value so it would look like this

```
tn      | 2013-08-16  | pr   | for  | 112 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | pr   | agn  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | pr   | mid  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | ot   | for  | 112 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | ot   | agn  | 118 
tn      | 2013-08-16  | ot   | mid  | 118
```

now my search always says do sub functioning and get the max date and then do a join and join to the max date and i still get not what i want i understand the logic of it i just don't see why i am not getting the right values

Comment: cant you sort it by date?

Comment: Your example is confusing (and misleading) because the max date for all combinations is '2013-08-16'. Also try to avoid keywords (e.g. date, type, desc, value) when naming columns. Some of them (e.g. `desc`) are reserved, and all of them cause confusion when being reviewed by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt as required...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT `cntryd`
            , `type`
            , `desc`
            , MAX(date) max_date
         FROM my_table
        GROUP
           BY `cntryd`
            , `type`
            , `desc`
     ) y
    ON y.cntryd = x.cntryd
   AND y.type = x.type
   AND y.desc = x.desc
   AND y.max_date = x.date;
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what i have its just u have added extrain the group by and AND comment, let me add the extra as u did and let me see

Comment: Yeah because the i was getting the data apart from the values but when added the extra part i hope i getting the right values, just gave some one the data to look at, i still don't understand it but if the data is correct, who am i to argue.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table)`

And you are done.

Comment: What if the same date is for two different value

Comment: OP wants max date of table - and that requirement is met. If there are 4 Values with the same date, all 4 are returned. So wheres the problem?

Comment: @sorry, overlooked that, have removed my minus 1

Comment: dates is going to be differnt on and off as well as cntrycd is going to be different types so i want a group of mid,for,agn for pr and ot and then by country

Comment: @dognose In which case one of us has misunderstood the OP's requirements.